# Tksbrokerapi не устанавливается

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я установил tksbrokerapi через `pip install tksbrokerapi`, после чего попробовал его запустить командой в повершеле.
вывело:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mako'`
я установил модуль mako, после чего появилась ошибка `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Templates'`.
После установки Templates ничего не меняется и все еще возникает ошибка о том что уже установленный модуль Templates отсутствует.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Модуль TKSBrokerAPI тестировался для версий python >= 3.9 . В более ранних версиях будут возникать ошибки. Может проблема именно в этом?

Попробуйте проверить действительность установки модулей выдающих ошибку с помощью команды "pip show *имя_модуля*"

Также можно использовать модуль TKSBrokerAPI, скачав его напрямую из [репозитория](https://github.com/Tim55667757/TKSBrokerAPI/) через git clone и взяв кодовую базу любого протестированного [релиза](https://github.com/Tim55667757/TKSBrokerAPI/releases).

Comment: Я тестировал на python 3.9; 3.10; 3.11 и  везде одна и та же ошибка. Модуль Templates установлен и pip show это показывает. В любом случае все решается установкой напрямую с репозитория.